# String to floating point conversion with support for both decimal point and decimal comma

Tags: c++

How do I convert a string to a floating point number if I want both comma interpreted as decimal comma and point interpreted as decimal point?

The code parses text files that have been created by our customers. They sometimes use decimal points and sometimes decimal commas but never thousand separators.

Comment: you can't substitute the commas for a decimal point as a pre-processing step? The localisation facets in iostreams would be the way forward, but good luck trying to figure them out...

Comment: I agree with Nim, whenever I do this I simply normalise the input data before processing

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Use `std::replace` to do the hard work:

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>

double toDouble(std::string s){
    std::replace(s.begin(), s.end(), ',', '.');
    return std::atof(s.c_str());
}
```

If you need to cope with thousands separators it'd be much more tricky.

Answer (score 4):

Just search for the decimal comma `','` and convert it to a `'.'`, then use `atof` from `<cstdlib>`:

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cstdio>
#include <string>

double toDouble(std::string s){
    // do not use a reference, since we're going to modify this string
    // If you do not care about ',' or '.' in your string use a 
    // reference instead.
    size_t found = s.find(",");
    if(found != std::string::npos)
        s[found]='.'; // Change ',' to '.'
    return std::atof(s.c_str());
}

int main(){
    std::string aStr("0.012");
    std::string bStr("0,012");

    double aDbl = toDouble(aStr);
    double bDbl = toDouble(bStr);

    std::printf("%lf %lf\n",aDbl,bDbl);
    return 0;    
}
```

If you use a C string instead of `std::string` use `strchr`from [`<cstring>`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstring/strchr/) to change your original string (don't forget to change it back or work on a locale copy if you need the original version afterwards).

Comment: Be careful with either of the two symbols being used as thousands separator though! Depending on your input you could convert `100.546,89` to `100.546.89` which is not a legal number. Be sure to check for that

Comment: @Nick: I agree, however OP has stated that "They sometimes use decimal points and sometimes decimal commas but *never thousand separators*", so this problem shouldn't occur.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do it as part of the normal reading of an `std::istream` you would create a custom `std::num_get<...>` facet, put it into a `std::locale` object, and install that into your stream using `imbue()` (or by setting the `std::locale` as the global locale before creating the stream).

Comment: Can I create a custom std::num_get<...> facet without writing my own floating point parser from scratch?

Comment: Well, yes and no. The interesting part of floating point parsing is transforming a string into a `double`. This e.g. `strtod()` can do. However, you'll beed to put the characters for this together. This is a bit annoying but not that hard.